# How to fix systemd-resolve on ubuntu?

Tags: linux, dns, nameserver, resolv.conf

systemd-reslove seems to be working

[image]

However DNS is slow if

```
nameserver 127.0.0.253
```

It works fine if I replace that with

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Is resolving names using the `systemd-resolve` tool also slow?

Comment: I am assuming so. Not sure how to confirm otherwise.